# TinyMCE 4 - Dynamically add buttons with a callback function

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-worker, tinymce-4

Having a little bit of trouble explaining what I am trying to do in writing, so it I sound stupid, sorry.

I am trying to create a worker to implement TinyMCE into the Web Experience Toolkit, this would give me full control to swap out editors at will in the future, without fear of breaking my view code. However I am falling into a little trouble with having more than one button on an editor in a for loop. So let me explain a bit of my code.

In the view code below i am sending my worker an aaaaCustomButton, which expects to take four values per button. A name, a title, a text and a callback function. as Seen here:

**View Code**

```
<textarea id="editbox" class="wet-boew-editor" data-wet-boew='{"iHeight": 175, "bFileMenu": false, "aaaaCustomButton": [["glossary", "Insert Glossary Term", "Insert Glossary Term","insertGlossaryWindow",], ["wrap", "test", "test","testCallback",]]}'></textarea>
```

This all works fine, both buttons are displayed from the addButton loop as seen below:

**For Loop**

```
setup: function (ed) {                                 
                        for(var k = 0; k < buttonNames.length; k++)
                        {
                            var holder = buttonCallBackFunctions[k];
                            ed.addButton(buttonNames[k], {
                                title: buttonTitles[k],
                                text: buttonTexts[k],
                                onclick: function () { 
                                    eval(holder);
                                }
                            }); 
                        }                       
                    }
```

However the problem is the onclick event, ignoring the eval for now, as even I dislike using it (the problem happens even when using window.settings.) When I click te button, eval then looks for holder, and runs the event. This is great, this is what I want! Wrong! So lets say I have 2 buttons, test1 and test2. When the onclick event fires for test1, the last value of holder was "test2", if i have 7 buttons for example, and pressed button test1, test7 is the value in holder.

Now to solve this I have been trying to hack it together various ways, such as get the name or id of the button, then go and get the callback from that, but i can't seem to get the id or name of the clicked button in TinyMCE.

If anybody an come up with a solution for this, that would be great. For now I am shelving this and moving on with other things that are more important, so take your time if necessary. I have included the full worker code below.

**Full Worker Code**

```
(function ($) {
    "use strict";
    var _pe = window.pe || {
        fn: {}
    }; /* local reference */
    _pe.fn.editor = {
        type: 'plugin',
        depends: ['tinymce'],
        mobile: function (elm) {
            return elm;
        },
        _exec: function (elm) {
            if (_pe.mobile) {
                return;
            }

            var opts,
                overrides,
                menuBar,
                toolBar;    

            var buttonNames = [];
            var buttonTitles = [];
            var buttonTexts = []; 
            var buttonCallBackFunctions = [];

            //Defaults
            opts = {
                aaaaCustomButton:[], // [0] Button Name, [1] Button Title, [2] Button Text, [3] Callback Function
                iHeight : 300,
                iWidth : 'auto',
                bEditorIsPrintOnly : false, //if this option is true, all other option become redundant
                bFileMenu : true,
                bEditMenu : true,
                bInsertMenu : true,
                bViewMenu : true,
                bFormatMenu : true,
                bTableMenu : true,
                bToolsMenu : true,
                bShowMenuBar : true, //if this is false all menu values above become redundant
                bShowToolBar : true,
                bShowStatusBar : true,          
                sLanguage : pe.language,
            };

            // Class-based overrides - use undefined where no override of defaults or settings.js should occur
            overrides = {};

            // Extend the defaults with settings passed through settings.js (wet_boew_editor), class-based overrides and the data-wet-boew attribute
            $.extend(opts, (typeof wet_boew_editor !== 'undefined' ? wet_boew_editor : {}), overrides, _pe.data.getData(elm, 'wet-boew'));

            //
            menuBar = opts.bFileMenu ? "file " : "";
            menuBar += opts.bEditMenu ? "edit " : "";
            menuBar += opts.bInsertMenu ? "insert " : "";
            menuBar += opts.bViewMenu ? "view " : "";
            menuBar += opts.bFormatMenu ? "format " : "";
            menuBar += opts.bTableMenu ? "table " : "";
            menuBar += opts.bToolsMenu ? "tools " : ""; 

            //
            if(opts.aaaaCustomButton.length > 0)
            {
                toolBar = "";
                for(var i = 0; i < opts.aaaaCustomButton.length; i++)
                {           
                    buttonNames[i] = opts.aaaaCustomButton[i][0];   
                    buttonTitles[i] = opts.aaaaCustomButton[i][1];
                    buttonTexts[i] = opts.aaaaCustomButton[i][2];
                    buttonCallBackFunctions[i] = opts.aaaaCustomButton[i][3] + "(ed)";
                    toolBar += opts.aaaaCustomButton[i][0] + " ";   
                }       
            }

            //Initializing editor       
            if(!opts.bEditorIsPrintOnly)
            {
                tinymce.init({
                    mode: "none",
                    theme: "modern",
                    entity_encoding : "raw",
                    plugins: "pagebreak,textcolor,table,hr,link,preview,searchreplace,print,paste,visualchars,nonbreaking,template,wordcount,code,contextmenu", 
                    menubar: opts.bShowMenuBar ? menuBar.trim() : false,    
                    statusbar: opts.bShowStatusBar,
                    toolbar: opts.bShowToolBar ? toolBar + '" | undo redo | forecolor backcolor | bold italic underline strikethrough | outdent alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify indent | bullist numlist hr |",' : false,
                    contextmenu: 'undo redo | cut copy paste |',
                    height: opts.iHeight,
                    width: opts.iWidth,
                    language : opts.sLanguage, 
                    setup: function (ed) {                                 
                        for(var k = 0; k < buttonNames.length; k++)
                        {
                            var holder = buttonCallBackFunctions[k];
                            ed.addButton(buttonNames[k], {
                                title: buttonTitles[k],
                                text: buttonTexts[k],
                                onclick: function () { 
                                    eval(holder);
                                }
                            }); 
                        }                       
                    }           
                });             
            }
            else //A non editable for printing
            {
                tinymce.init({
                    mode: "none",
                    theme: "modern",
                    entity_encoding : "raw",
                    plugins: "print,wordcount,noneditable,autoresize",
                    menubar: false,
                    toolbar: "print",
                    contextmenu: false,
                    statusbar: false,       
                    language : opts.sLanguage, 
                    setup: function (ed) {
                        ed.on('PreInit', function (event) {
                            var ed = event.target, dom = ed.dom;
                            dom.setAttrib(ed.getBody(), 'contenteditable', 'false');
                        });
                    }
                }); 
            }

            tinymce.execCommand("mceAddEditor", true, elm.attr('id'));                      
        } // end of exec
    };
    window.pe = _pe;
    return _pe;
} (jQuery));
```

Answer (score 1):

> but i can't seem to get the id or name of the clicked button in
>   TinyMCE.

Well i cannot provide you the buttons id but this can give you the name of clicked button.

```
setup : function(ed) {
       ed.on('ExecCommand',function(e){
           alert(e.command, e.ui, e.value);        
        })
    }
```

Check this link -

http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/api4:class.tinymce.CommandEvent

You can also check my last Posted Answer here -

[tinymce - adding a custom code / change value of a html element, when any of buttons is clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24801549/tinymce-adding-a-custom-code-change-value-of-a-html-element-when-any-of-but/24802536#24802536)

OR Check Demo - [**WORKING DEMO**](http://fiddle.tinymce.com/cpeaab)